# Why is my API request returning a 400 response using HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, openweathermap

I'm creating a simple Rails app that fetches data from the Open Weather Map API and returns the current weather data of the city that is searched for in a form field. I would like an API call to look like this for example:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=berlin&APPID=111111`

I've tested this in Postman with my API key it works fine but with my code it returns `"cod":"400","message":"Nothing to geocode"`

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Here is my code.

services/open_weather_api.rb

```
class OpenWeatherApi
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://api.openweathermap.org"

  def initialize(city = "Berlin,DE", appid = "111111")
    @options = { query: { q: city, APPID: appid } }
  end

  def my_location_forecast
    self.class.get("/data/2.5/weather", @options)
  end
end
```

forecasts_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  def current_weather
    @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@options).my_location_forecast
  end
end
```

current_weather.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(current_weather_forecasts_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %><br>

<%= @forecast %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'forecasts#current_weather'
  resources :forecasts do
    collection do
      get :current_weather
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is your API key rightly configured in `config/initializers/open-weather-api.rb` ? `config.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

Comment: @BTL No, my API key is in my service class at the moment. When I get this to work I will add it to my encrypted credentials.

Comment: Can you show us the value of `@options` in your `ForcastsController`

Comment: @AsimHashmi It's in the code above, in my service class.

Comment: @Steve you are also passing `@options`  here `OpenWeatherApi.new(@options).my_location_forecast`

Comment: It's the controller code, so I don't think that this `@options` variable will be coming from service

Comment: @AsimHashmi True! Not sure why `@options` is in the controller. I've deleted it now and I get the response I expect :) My search field doesn't work though - any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error describes itself:

```
"cod":"400","message":"Nothing to geocode"
```

it means that you didn't provide it the city in your query. One possible cause of this error is that you are overriding the default value in your `initialize` method with the `@options` variable from the controller in this line:

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  def current_weather
    @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@options).my_location_forecast
  end
end
```

From the information you provided, you've not defined the `@options` variable in your controller or it is `nil`. So this is overriding the default value of the `initialize` method in `OpenWeatherApi` .
Since the appid in your case will not change, only the city name will change so you can send it from controller.

```
def current_weather
  @city = params[:city] // the city you want to send to API. Change it with your value
  @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@city).my_location_forecast
end
```